# Woocommerce Product page filter the Category text

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to use a filter to change the category output on product page in woocommerce?

What i'm after is to display root category and sub category, right now my theme only displays the sub category on product page and best would be if there was an filter to alter the output.

For example:

```
Category: <a href="/mycatA">MycatA</a>
```

But i would want to display

```
Category: <a href="/mycatA">MycatA</a>, <a href="/rootCatA">RootCatA</a>
```